# Convert Country List to Continent List in Bash

Tags: bash

I am doing some geoip lookups using the `geoiplookup` command in Linux. This correctly returns the country codes for me but I need to break them down into continents instead of countries. I currently have a text file full of countries and am trying to determine the best way to convert these to continents using `bash`. I have a second text file called conversion and it looks like this:

```
United States:North America
Mexico:North America
Canada:North America
Argentina:South America
Bolivia:South America
Brazil:South America 
Chile:South America
etc.
```

I was thinking of doing some sort of loop for the name in the `geo.txt` file and grep the conversion.txt file and then print out anything after the `:`. I highly doubt that is the easiest/best way so just wanted to get a few opinions on it.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Currently I have broken down into different files a username, and geo ip and I'm merging those into one file. So I basically want to match up the username to the continent instead of the username to the country. So a txt file or continent is fine as long as it's in the same order that the country one was since that maps to the username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the opposite of your proposition:

Loop on the coutry:continent (conversion.txt) file and use sed to make the change in a copy of geo.txt:

```
GEO_FILE="geo.txt"
CONVERSION_FILE="conversion.txt"

TARGET_FILE="continent-${GEO_FILE}"

cp "${GEO_FILE}" "${TARGET_FILE}"

while read LINE; do
  COUNTRY="$(echo "${LINE}" | cut --delimiter=':' --fields=1)"
  CONTINENT="$(echo "${LINE}" | cut --delimiter=':' --fields=2)"

  command sed -i -e "s/${COUNTRY}/${CONTINENT}/g" "${TARGET_FILE}"
done < "${CONVERSION_FILE}"

more "${TARGET_FILE}"
```

Answer (score 2):

The geoiplookup command provides information in the form

```
GeoIP Country Edition: US, United States
```

So you can get the country information with

```
export IP=serverfault.com
country=$(geoiplookup "$IP" | awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} ; {print $2}' | sed 's/^ //')
echo $country
United States
```

You can then pass this to awk

```
awk -v search="$country" 'BEGIN {FS=":"} ; $0 ~ search {print $2}' conversion.txt
North America
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for you to put some error checking and other niceties into a script.

Comment: Hmmm.... I got your initial script working fine so I was going to try to put it in a for loop with multiple countries already in there and it fails. ---for i in `cat /tmp/tmp.txt`; do awk -v search="$i" 'BEGIN {FS=":"} ; $0 ~ search {print $2}' /tmp/conversion.txt; done--- It technically does the lookups but instead of outputting 7 continents to match the 7 countries, I get 23 continent outputs. I'll dig into it deeper. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you don't want to do is invoke sed/grep/awk for every iteration of a loop:

```
awk -F: 'NR==FNR {c[$1]=$2;next} {print c[$0]}' conversion.txt geo.txt > continents.txt
```